# Cannot find module '@nestjs-modules/mailer' or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: nestjs, package.json, nodemailer

When I am running docker container server fails with the following error:

```
src/modules/mailer/mail-queue.processor.ts:2:31 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@nestjs-modules/mailer' or its corresponding type 
declarations.
```

My import:

```
import { MailerService } from '@nestjs-modules/mailer';
```

package.json:

```
"@nestjs-modules/mailer": "^1.8.1",
```

Same thing happens with HandlebarsAdapter even thought it's in package.json as well.

```
import { HandlebarsAdapter } from '@nestjs-modules/mailer/dist/adapters/handlebars.adapter';
```

Please help.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:16.17.0-buster

RUN mkdir -p /server/node_modules
RUN chown -R node:node /server/node_modules
WORKDIR /server

# Install Dependencies
COPY package.json ./
RUN npm install --force

COPY . .
```

Comment: Did you run your package install inside of docker? Can you share your dockerfile?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel just added Dockerfile

Comment: @OleksandraKrupnova have you been able to fix this issue? I to am having it.

Comment: @Gdfelt i don’t remember exactly but i think i removed the container and image and ran docker compose up again. but ended up switching to nodemailer anyway because couldn’t get mailer to send emails